# Is it known that P $\neq$ NP implies BQP $\neq$ NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing, p-vs-np

Pretty much the title. Is there any result that shows that $P \neq NP \Rightarrow BQP \neq NP$. I think it's pretty clear that $BQP \neq NP \Rightarrow P \neq NP$, as $P$ is a subclass of $BQP$. But is anything know about the former problem?

Comment: No. See e.g. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6154/consequences-of-sat-in-bqp, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3304/bqp-vs-qma.

Comment: It consistent with current knowledge that $P \subsetneq \textrm{RP} = \textrm{PSPACE}$, which would contradict the title.

Comment: It is also far from incontrovertible that BQP$\ne$NP$\Rightarrow$P$\ne$NP, at least because BQP likely contain problems *outside* of NP, e.g. problems without any polynomial-size witnesses, and the disjoint union of BQP and NP is likely non-empty.  What I think you meant is that BQP$\subsetneq$NP$\Rightarrow$P$\ne$NP, which does follow from the inclusion of P in BQP.